# Triggering Laravel observers on multiple records

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have been using [Laravel Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers) to handle my app logic whenever my models get deleted/updated/saved. I noticed in some cases these observers don't get triggered. For example if I use

```
Model::where(active,1)->update([some stuff]);
```

the observers never get triggered. It is very annoying to have to fetch all records and run a forloop on each instance and call update. Is there a way around this or are there any good practices to handle these scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Model::where(active,1)->update([some stuff]);
```

Query Builder's `update()` method is executed instead of Eloquent's `update()` method.

If you want to trigger Eloquent events, you need to update rows one by one.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without forloop? I know if I call first() or find() it turns it into eloquent. But how about multiple rows

Comment: @HiradRoshandel if you want to update all rows with one query, Eloquent events will not be fired. You can fire these events manually, but it's tricky and it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Events and listeners instead? You can run the update either raw or query builder, pass those effected rows in the event.